# Context Free Grammar Advantages

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions

I am currently learning about context-free grammar, however, I am confused as to why context-free grammar is used over regular languages(Regular expression) and what makes CFG more powerful. Even though the structure is more complex than regular expressions. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please focus on one question.

Comment: You should be able to answer that question yourself after you learn a few things about the Chomsky hierarchy. But just in case you have a different definition of "learning" than I do, try this: create a regular language which recognises exactly those sequence of `(` and `)` in which the parentheses balance correctly. (And note that "parsing" is not actually just about recognising which inputs match a pattern. It's also about analysing the input into a collection of inter-related parts (hence the word "parse").

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up a high-quality archive of knowledge, in the format of questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but to others in the future.  Answerers may be answering from that perspective, so it can be considered impolite to delete the question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 2):

While regular languages can allow some particular search (see [Grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)), where context-free languages shine is in compilation.

Regular languages can be used to do a lexical analysis, meaning it can recognize lexemes in code. For example, lexical analysis can tell you that `42hello` or `if<=>!` are illegal part of code in C. However, what regular languages lack is an advanced memory. They can't be used, for example, if there are the same number of opening and closing parentheses, or if thoses are in a correct order.

This can be done by syntax analysis, using context-free grammars. The syntax analysis is used to create a parse tree, most necessary for compilation.

On a more formal approach, as an example why context-free languages are more vast than regular languages, the language $L = \{a^nb^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ is a well-known non-regular language (this can be proven using the pumping lemma). However, the grammar $S\to aSb\mid \varepsilon$ generates $L$.